# how to allow different inputs only from the same 'number'

Tags: mysql

I do not want to register repeated `msg` from the same `number`, but if there adds to `dup` counter

```
INSERT INTO sms (number, msg) 
  VALUES (%s, %s)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE dup = dup+1
```

how to allow different inputs only from the same `number`?

Answer (score 1):

You would add a unique index on `number`:

```
create unique index idx_sms_number on sms(number)
```

Note:  I assume that the "%s" means that you will put valid values there.  Your statement is not valid SQL as written.

Comment: the idea is to allow messages from any number, but I do not want to register repeated messages from the same number, in which case only update the repeated message counter

Answer (score 1):

You can add a composite primary key to your table with a combination of msg and number:

ex: 
`PRIMARY KEY (msg, number)` 
in your table creation